# "opservice is null false" message in Debug console when tap screen

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

We are creating a simple App with Flutter, and when I try to debug in an Android device (not an emulator), I get this message in my debug console in VSCode (several times):

```
I/Surface (17948): opservice is null false
```

It appears at random times when I tap something in the App, in mobile screen.

Do you know why we get this message and how to solve it?

Comment: I receive this too. It appears to be from a loop that doesn't exit properly in time. I am dealing with inputs in SDL though.

Comment: Are you tapping on widget kind GestureDetector? Or Do you have any bool variable on screen?

Comment: https://python5.com/q/mgjkteee

same question :)

Comment: https://www.soinside.com/question/Nh5oMpbw7N9CUbb46jM9zk

another same question.

Comment: Is it a OnePlus device? I often see this message while debugging on OnePlus devices when you try to touch or drag at the very sides or corner of the screen.

Comment: @bluenile Seems like it. It happens in my OnePlus but not on emulators I test on.

Comment: Hmm... Is the issue still there?  It doesn't seem to be on my OnePlus phone...

Comment: Found [this GitHub post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65626), it seems that this error is reproducible in a particular device such as OnePlus. If that is not the case, could you provide [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you are trying to test and the output when running `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: This question could use a [repro]

Answer (score 1):

when you attach your phone, debugger is not debuging your app only,
maybe there are apps built using flutter in your phone that the debugger also shows thier logs,
try to attach your phone without running the app and watch the log.